# JSF 1.1 and Ajax4jsf not working properly on Websphere 6.1

Tags: ajax, jsf

I am working with JSF 1.1, Ajax4JSF. What I find is, if I enable `a4j:support` for some of JSF's inputText items, it is not working as expected. I have something like this in the code

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.desc}">
<a4j:support event="onkeyup" reRender="id"/>
</h:inputText>
```

And what I find is, sometimes it does not work, for example, I type `TEST` on the input text box and what transfers is only the `"T"` to the backing bean.

One more problem that I see is, when I submit the form, some of the values are not getting set in the backing bean. The setter methods are not called at all.

I do not think this is working properly in my env, is it this combination of JSF1.1,Ajax4JSF and websphere6.1 is not supported or is there anyway I can troubleshoot this ?

EDIT :

Sometimes when I am producing ajax messages by some event like onkeyup, I get the following error (this does not come always but at times) -

```
Request Error:status : 500 Internal Server Error Message: undefined.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience of deploying to Websphere, but i'd be surprised if your ajax problem was a result of the deployment environment...

There's one obvious potential problem that jumps out once reading the markup; you've setup your ajax callback to trigger `onkeyup`... so it makes sense that T is being passed to the backing bean, as releasing the T key will invoke the call. You might want to consider using a better javascript event, perhaps onblur.